# scanner class error while producing an output text file

Tags: java, swing, console

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class cat
{
int t,n[],m[];
private void input()throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    n=new int[t];
    m=new int[t];
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        n[i]=s.nextInt();//line 15
        m[i]=s.nextInt();
    }
}

private void calc(int n, int m)
{
    double c=0.0;
    if(n==1 && m==1)
        System.out.println("Multiple");
    else
    {
        c=((n*m)-1.0)/(n-1);
        if(c==Math.ceil(c))
            System.out.println(Math.round(c));
        else
            System.out.println("Not possible");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    cat ob=new cat();
    ob.input();
    for(int i=0;i<ob.t;i++)
    {
        ob.calc(ob.n[i],ob.m[i]);
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to execute this program by taking inputs from a file which i have created at this location `C:\input\input1.txt`and it will produce an output file at `C:\output\output1.txt`. But when i execute my class file `java cat <C:\input\input1.txt> C:\output\output1.txt` i get the following error and a 0KB file gets generated in the output folder.HELP

ERROR[image]

Comment: Where are you taking the input from? According to your explanation from a file, according to your code from System.in. Please clarify this issue to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NoSuchElementException` occurs when the input is exhausted, i.e. there is no next element in the `Scanner`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) is a link to the corresponding Java API.

Comment: If I understood you right, you are reading the first value and use it as size for the arrays `m` and `n`. The values read afterwards are stored (alternating) in both arrays. As Kakarot mentioned, you should make use of `scanner.hasNextInt()` to ensure that input is available. Be sure to think of all possible cases, like i) no input avail at all, ii) input for both arrays avail and iii) input for `n` avail, but not for `m`. You could also try to catch the NoSuchElementException and interpret its occurrence as a criteria for malformed input data.

Answer (score 1):

Before making the Scanner move to the next element its always a good practice to check if the next element exists. You can do that by adding the following line of code :

```
if(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
   // get nextInt(), next()....
   n[i]=s.nextInt();
}

if(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
    m[i]=s.nextInt();
}
```